Descriptive table in R with more than one grouping variable
I have a data frame that looks like below.
#Grouping Var1
var1<-sample(c("red",'blue', 'orange'), size=100, replace=T)
var2<-sample(c("US", "Canada", "Europe"), size=100, replace=T)
var3<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
head(df)

How do I create a table in R that looks roughly like this? I feel like a function in gtsummary or janitor should work, but I cannot figure it out.



Categorical_Variable
Mean_var3




var1
empty


red
0.2


blue
0.3


orange
0.1


var2
empty


Canada
0.1


US
0.5


Europe
1




Here is how you can do it with gtsummary.
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.7.2'

var1<-sample(c("red",'blue', 'orange'), size=100, replace=T)
var2<-sample(c("US", "Canada", "Europe"), size=100, replace=T)
var3<-rnorm(100)
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)


tbl_continuous(
  data = df, 
  variable = var3, 
  statistic = ~"{mean}"
) |> 
  as_kable()




Characteristic
N = 100




var1



blue
-0.11


orange
0.01


red
-0.47


var2



Canada
-0.32


Europe
0.02


US
-0.23



Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Thanks, I knew there was a way.

One more thing: Is there a way to summarize two or more continuous variables in the same way? So, a var4<-rnorm(100, mean=2, sd=2)?

tidyverse solution:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(var1 = sample(c("red", "blue", "orange"), 100, replace = T),
                 var2 = sample(c("US", "Canada", "Europe"),  100, replace = T),
                 var3 = rnorm(100))

df1 <- df |>
  pivot_longer(-var3,
               values_to = "Categorical_Variable") |>
  summarise(Mean_var3 = as.character(sprintf("%.2f", mean(var3))), 
            .by = c(name, Categorical_Variable)) |>
  group_by(name) |>
  group_modify(~ add_row(.x, .before = 0)) |>
  mutate(Categorical_Variable = if_else(is.na(Categorical_Variable),
                                        name, Categorical_Variable),
         Mean_var3 = if_else(is.na(Mean_var3),
                             "", Mean_var3)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  select(-name)

data.frame(df1)  
#   Categorical_Variable Mean_var3
# 1                 var1          
# 2                 blue     -0.08
# 3               orange      0.11
# 4                  red      0.08
# 5                 var2          
# 6               Canada      0.17
# 7               Europe      0.02
# 8                   US     -0.10


Another tidyverse approach:
my_fun <- function(df, var) {
  df |> 
    summarize(mean_var = mean(var3), .by = {{var}}) |>
    rename("category" = 1) |>
    add_row(category = rlang::as_name(rlang::quo(expr = {{var}})), .before = 1)
}
bind_rows(my_fun(df, var1), 
          my_fun(df, var2))

Result
  category    mean_var
1     var1          NA
2      red -0.15776396
3   orange -0.06591007
4     blue -0.10662443
5     var2          NA
6   Canada -0.01538330
7       US -0.13386312
8   Europe -0.19183905

